# Python webdriver: driver.get(URL) does not open in unittest - works through console

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Just as the title says I have a copy of Selenium
 - installed from svn repo

When I import and run things through the console everything works
when I try to run a unittest even one exported directly from Selenium IDE

it will open the browser and hang without trying to open a URL

**Additional Details**

- OS: Ubuntu 11.04
- Python: 2.7
- Browser: Firefox 7.0.1

  - tried with HTTPUNIT though I kept getting illegal character errors

**Code**

```
import unittest
#import time
import re

from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#from local_config import BASE_URL, BASE_FOLDER, DRIVER
BASE_URL = 'http://localhost'
BASE_FOLDER = '/dir/to/site/'
DRIVER = 'FIREFOX'


class CheckSitemap(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        global BASE_URL
        global DRIVER
        if DRIVER == 'FIREFOX':
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        elif DRIVER == 'HTTPUNIT':
            self.driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
        else:
            raise Exception('DRIVER not set')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = BASE_URL
#        print self.base_url
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def getSitemap(self):
        global BASE_FOLDER
        global DRIVER
#        print BASE_FOLDER
        driver = self.driver
        op1 = '%ssitemap.xml' % BASE_FOLDER
        if DRIVER == 'HTTPUNIT':
            op1 = '%s%s' % (self.base_url, op1[1:len(op1)])
#        print op1
        driver.get(op1.replace('//', '/'))
#        print 'HELLO WORLD!!'
        urls = []
#        print driver.page_source
        r = re.compile(r'<a href="(.*?)"')
        for match in r.finditer(driver.page_source):
            urls.append(match.group(1))
        if len(urls) == 0:
            r = re.compile(r'<loc>(.*?)</loc>', re.DOTALL)
            for match in r.finditer(driver.page_source):
                urls.append(match.group(1).strip())
        return urls

    def test_check_sitemap(self):
        global DRIVER
        driver = self.driver
        urls = self.getSitemap()
#        print urls
        for url in urls:
            if DRIVER == 'HTTPUNIT':
                driver.get(url)
            else:
                driver.get(url.replace(self.base_url, ''))

            if re.search(r"\.php on line [0-9]+", driver.page_source):
                self.verificationErrors.append('php error on %s' % url)

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
#        print self.verificationErrors
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

any ideas?

Comment: So can you confirm that the regex in getSitemap is finding any matches?  I don't have the sitemap.xml to test your code but what happens if you print the return from urls in both the for loop and the len of urls in getSitemap function

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution by chatting with AutomatedTester in IRC

currently the python webdriver implementation ignores the self.base_url value

so when you .get() a URL you need to use the full URL

a bug report has been filed and will likely be updated in the near future

Webdriver version 2.11.1